# HTML5 requestanimation frame

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, sprite

so I wrote a basic game using requestAnimationFrame. It redraws the canvas and listens for keyboard input and moves the player in pixels/sec accordingly. My question is, given a sprite sheet containing 9 frames, how do I create this animation while the player is walking? Basically if(walking){ loop through those nine frames at a given rate }. I understand how the game loop works, just not how to animate the sprite sheet.

Comment: Well, do as you said. Set a flag to `true` when it is walking and to false when it stops walking (probably in `keydown`/`keyup` or some smarter logic), then use your `if (walking)` logic into the game loop.

Comment: your player or your walking sequence object should contain a `next()` function, so that at each step, the actual image to be plotted is advanced by the "next" function, called by some event.

Comment: I think if you post some code, people will be more prone to add (useful/right) answers than comments.

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries out there for the animation itself, but it is easy enough on your own.

You'll need to use drawImage:

```
ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sw, sh);
```

Supposing that the sprite sheet is in horizontal format:

```
var frame = 0;
ctx.drawImage(image, startX+(spriteWidth*frame), startYy, spriteWidth, spriteHeight);
```

Simply update the frame per how many ticks or seconds you would like to step through the animation. That can be in any manner such as suggested in the comments.

A modulus function will keep `frame` in bounds:

```
frame = frame % numberOfFrames;
```

I prefer to just make an animated sprite class and use it. It is more fun. That is the basics of how it works. Hope that helps.